# My component function is not re-rendering after state change even that I matched the state, returned new state and connected the component,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I was looking into this problem in similar posts but I just can't figure it out and I kinda need an advice. So basically my functional component is not re running after I returned a new state from the reducer. The reducer looks like this:

```
export interface ProductsTableState {
  products: Product[];
  isLoading: boolean;
}

const initialState: ProductsTableState = {
  products: [],
  isLoading: false,
};

export const ProductsTableReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: ProductsTableActionsInterface
): ProductsTableState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ProductsTableActionsEnum.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
      // CONSOLE LOG
      console.log("Request in REDUCER");
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
      };
    case ProductsTableActionsEnum.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      console.log("Success in reducer");
      return {
        ...state,
        products: action.payload,
        isLoading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And in the second case state, I get the message in console, so there is running.
So in the reducer I think I returned a NEW state so the change should be visible by the connection. Because reading I saw multiple problems that if you modify the current state it will not be detected so you need to return a new one.

For the saga and store the code looks like this:
Saga:

```
function* getAllProductsAsync() {
  try {
    const result: Product[] = yield call(() => getProducts());
    // CONSOLE LOG
    console.log("SAGA");
    console.log(result);

    yield put(getAllProductsSuccess(result));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(getAllProductsError());
  }
}

export function* watchGetAllProductsAsync() {
  yield takeEvery(
    ProductsTableActionsEnum.GET_ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST,
    getAllProductsAsync
  );
}
```

And store :

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export const store = createStore(
  ProductsTableReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
);

sagaMiddleware.run(watchGetAllProductsAsync);

export interface AppState {
  products: ProductsTableState;
}
```

And the most important  I think its the functional component where I have the problem. Mostly is a Redux - Axios React app. So what is actually happening is that when I firstly load the page, I get nothing on it. If I comment a line here and save the page reload with my products, because at the second render the products are viseble in the state. As far as I could figure it out I think my problem should be with the mapStateWithProps and the connect but it looks fine for me.

```
interface ProductsTableProps {
  products: Product[];
  isLoading: boolean;
}

export const TableProducts = (props: ProductsTableProps) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getAllProductsRequest());
  }, []);

  // CONSOLE LOG
  console.log(store.getState().products);

  // CONSOLE LOG
  console.log(props.products);

  const classes = useStyles();
  const items = store.getState().products.map((product) => (
    <tr className={classes.trStyle}>
      <td className={classes.thtdStyle}>{product.productCategoryDto.name}</td>
      <td className={classes.thtdStyle}>{product.name}</td>
      <td className={classes.thtdStyle}>{product.price}</td>
      <td key={product.id}>
        <Link to={{ pathname: `/product/${product.id}`, state: { product } }}>
          <IconButton className={classes.buttonStyle}>
            <InfoIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Link>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return (
    <table className={classes.tableStyle}>
      <thead className={classes.theadStyle}>
        <tr>
          <th className={classes.thtdStyle}>Category</th>
          <th className={classes.thtdStyle}>Name</th>
          <th className={classes.thtdStyle}>Price</th>
          <th className={classes.thtdStyle}>Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody className={classes.trStyle}>{items}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  products: state.products.products,
  isLoading: state.products.isLoading,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  getAllProd: () => dispatch(getAllProductsRequest()),
  getAllProdSuccess: (products: Product[]) =>
    dispatch(getAllProductsSuccess(products)),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getAllProductsRequest,
  getAllProductsSuccess,
})(TableProducts);
```

Comment: can you provide your `reducer`?

Comment: the reducer is in the first code snippet, the 3rd function.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the problem in `mapStateToProps`. You can try update like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => ({
  products: state.products,
  isLoading: state.isLoading,
});
```

Comment: I understand what you mean by this change, but It doesn't work for my code, I get multiple incompatible types errors writing like this. I tried changing the types so I can use the function you provided to me but its the same problem about the component rendering.